# stop execution of JS on bootbox.alert() opening

Tags: javascript, alert, bootbox

I had such code:

```
alert('Error!');
window.location.reload();
```

It shows alert first and after closing of this alert page will be reloaded;

I want to use bootboxjs for bootstrap, and change my code:

```
bootbox.alert('Error!');
window.location.reload();
```

But it don't wait while alert will be closed by user and reloading page right after alert showing.
How to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use callback for this:

```
bootbox.alert('Error!', function() {
    window.location.reload();
});
```

look at official [documentation](http://bootboxjs.com/#api)

Comment: thank you!
common window.alert() has no callback, so I didn't think about it.